# Running gunicorn inside heroku docker

Tags: heroku, docker, foreman, docker-compose, docker-machine

I have the following procfile:

```
web: gunicorn application:app --config=gunicorn_config.py
```

When I run this using `foreman start` everything works fine, but when I run this inside a container using `docker-compose up web`, I get

```
web_1        | usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]
web_1        | gunicorn: error: No application module specified.
```

The process I'm using to build the container is as specified in [Heroku's docker guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/docker):

```
1. `heroku docker:init` to set up Dockerfile and docker compose configuration.
2. `docker-compose build` to create the image.
3. I always do a restart of my vm for good measure:  `docker-machine restart default && eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

Comment: Also having this issue.

Comment: Did you solve this ever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the gunicorn error message, you should write the app module after the --config option. Also you are to specify the config module (i.e. without .py) and specify that it is python.

=> Try this instead:

```
gunicorn --config python:gunicorn_config application:app
```